# Difference between "unto" and "to"

Tags: meaning, etymology, differences, word-usage

What are the differences between "unto" and "to"? It seems that in many contexts where the word "unto" is used, "to" could be substituted and would be perfectly correct. It reminds me of flammable/inflammable, where "flammable" came into use because the "in" in "inflammable" caused people to think that it meant *not* inflammable. Is this a similar situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*To*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/to) did not come from *[unto](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unto)* (if anything, vice versa), so the situation is not the same as with *flammable* and *inflammable*.  Though *to* is an older form, *unto* was never as prevalent, and is now either archaic, or used in limited contexts, such as shown [here](http://www.wordnik.com/words/unto%20itself) (Idiom: *unto itself*).

Comment: The curious may find examples illustrating the wide range of early senses of *unto* [here](http://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=id&id=MED50055&egs=all&egdisplay=open).

Answer (score 1):

The origin of *unto*, as reported from the *Oxford English Dictionary* is the following:

> ORIGIN: from *until* preposition with *to* preposition replacing northern equivalent *till* preposition.

Therefore, the relation between *to* and *unto* is not the same relation there is, e.g., between *touchable* and *untouchable*.

One of the meaning of *unto* reported from the same dictionary is *until*, *till*. The dictionary reports also that *unto* indicates "regular recurrence within specified units of time, as *day unto day*."

> Doctor Manley…praises Kate unto this day.—I. Maclaren

Comment: Though *to* can replace *unto* anywhere it appears in your examples, so *unto* still sounds a little archaic, even in those contexts.  The only times *unto* is still used are in idioms, where it cannot be replaced by *to* (as in the idiom "it is a [noun] *unto itself*").

Answer (score 0):

In the King James "unto" seems a bit like placing something like a gift or idea or anything with some kind of substance unto the person, place or thing/idea of acceptance. exp..."the river flows over the banks and unto the road" or "I wrote a letter unto you"
Now the word "to" is more of an expression in grammer in which the person, place or thing/idea is directly or indirectly expressed. exp..."I went into my room to write a letter unto you" I went to write unto you.

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  I find your answer a bit hard to follow. You might want to reread it and be more precise about your sources.  If you're going to cite to the King James translation of the Bible, why don't you consider using actual verses as examples and then comparing them to more modern translations of the same verses?

Comment: The KJV is the first place where I found `unto` used regularly instead of `to`. I am looking forward this explanation.

Answer (score -1):

"Unto" is just an older form of "To".

I've never seen anything to suggest that there was a confusion regarding "unto/to" akin to "inflammable/flammable".