# Meaning of archaic "unto"

Tags: meaning, archaicisms

What is the Biblical meaning of *unto*? I have looked it up in [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unto). But I am not satisfied with the answer. Jesus said in the New Testament

> Come unto me, all ye that labour and are heavy laden, and I will give you rest.
>
> <sub>Matthew 11:28.</sub>

Comment: It means exactly what it means in dictionary.com...to.

Comment: _Come unto_ is just an archaic form of _come to_. The language in the King James translation was intended to sound archaic in the early 17th century; it sounds **very** archaic now. That's why it's hard to understand.

Comment: I'm afraid that Jesus didn't actually use the word 'unto' on the occasion mentioned. And I'm sure He isn't happy about translations that sacrifice clarity for supposed venerable register: He spoke in the common language of the day during His 3 years of earthly ministry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between 'to' and 'unto'](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39352/difference-between-unto-and-to).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: And Santa Claus?

Comment: @Drew North Polish does not have a word for 'unto'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: It does now. A welcome addition unto NP, I'm sure.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NORAD_Tracks_Santa), Santa's ways aren't too mysterious. (The driver of the coach my wife and I were on for a marvellous tour of the SW states explained the Sears howler as we passed through Colorado Springs – he's a retired USAF man).

Comment: If you don't understand the King James wording, read the verse in [one of the other translations available on the web](http://biblehub.com/matthew/11-28.htm).

Comment: @Drew - Only 45 words spoken by Santa Claus have ever been recorded, and "unto" is not one of them.

Comment: Since there is no way of knowing what words were actually spoken wouldn't you have to go back to the original Greek word as it was finally put down in writing?

Comment: I would go to and join the Christianity stack exchange website to ask this question. Go to the upper left hand corner of your screen and click the drop down menu under stack exchange. Under "your communities" click "edit" on the right of that then search and add Christianity. I bet you'll have more luck getting votes and a answer to your question there. If you do not want to do it under Christianity, there are other religions you may search it under. I wish you best of luck and hope this was helpful.

Comment: @ErinJohnLevins - I don't think Jesus spoke Greek.

Comment: Right. IT was just that it was finally written down  in Greek in the New Teatament.

Answer (score 1):

The 'unto' as opposed to "to" used in Matthew 11:28 as in certain other scriptures appears to reinforce the meaning of a destination. ["Into" "Unto"] Many of the newer translations use the word 'to' which can be construed as being the same but it's usage is more generalized in application. "I will walk to the shops" - (not necessarily a destination.) "Give this parcel to the postie" "I will attach this to my bicycle" etc.